# replace column values with values in another list when values appear in a specific list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a list and a pandas dataframe

```
[ apple, tomato, mango ]
```

```
values 

tomato
pineapple
apple
banana
mango
```

I would like to replace the column values that appear in the list with the values in the new list as follow

```
[ fruit1, fruit2, fruit3 ]
```

My expected output is a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
values 

fruit2
pineapple
fruit1
banana
fruit3
```

How can I accomplish this efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `dict` and use the `map` function of a dataframe:

```
l1 = ["apple", "tomato", "mango"]
l2 = ["fruit1", "fruit2", "fruit3"]

df['values'].map(dict(zip(l1, l2))).fillna(df['values'])
```

`fillna` is needed because map by default will convert values that doesn't exists in `dict` to `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary with the `zip()` function and then replace the values:

```py
current = ['apple', 'tomato', 'mango']
to_replace = ['fruit1', 'fruit2', 'fruit3']

replace_dict = dict(zip(current, to_replace))

df.replace(replace_dict, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

```
      values
0     fruit2
1  pineapple
2     fruit1
3     banana
4     fruit3
```

The `replace` function replaces dataframe values. Hope it helps!